# onclick an a specific checkbox display a buttton.js hquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table with checkboxes. I was trying to display a button onlick of a particular checkboxes, currently the button is displaying but only for the first checkboxes, its not working for the remaining checkboxes. I have my test code below please help me to display of a button on click of a particular checkboxes. help will be highly appreciated.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```js
//this is how i am creating a dynamic table with checkbox

var table = document.getElementById('testbody');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < (test.length); i = i + 2) {
   
   var row = tablebody.insertRow(-1);
   
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
      
      cell1.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">'
     + test[i] + '</span>';//values from db
          
          cell2.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">'
     + test[i+1] + '</span>';//values form db
          //this is my checkbox
        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">';
}

//this is how im trying to display a button
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#your').change(function () {
        
        if (!this.checked)
            alert("test1");
        else 
           alert("test2");
    }).change();
});

 }
```

```html
//this is just an eg:
<table id="testtablet" >
  <thead>
   <tr >
    <td width="400px">
     
    </td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody id="testbody"></tbody>
  

 </table>
  //this is the button i was trying to display
 <button type="button" id="chochk" style="display:none" class="sukuti">event</button>
```

[1]:

Comment: "#your" should not be an id but a class, ".your" hence change id="your" to class="your" and $("#your") to $(".your")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Like suggested in the comment you can use **your** as a class.

You can attach the change event handler in a different way:

```
$('#testbody :checkbox.your').change(function (e) {
```

For dynamically added (in future, after the definition of change event handler) elements you can delegate the change event:

```
$('#testbody').on('change', ':checkbox.your', function (e) {
```

In order to toggle button visibility according to the checkbox state you can write:

```
$('#chochk').toggle(this.ckhecked);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test = ['06/12/2017', 'test', '06/13/2017', 'testing'];
    var table = document.getElementById('testbody');

    for (var i = 0; i < (test.length); i = i + 2) {

        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);

        cell1.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">'
                + test[i] + '</span>';//values from db

        cell2.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:20px;">'
                + test[i + 1] + '</span>';//values form db
        //this is my checkbox
        cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" class="your" value="yourCheckBoxVal">';
    }

    $('#testbody :checkbox.your').change(function (e) {
        console.log("test: " + this.checked);
        $('#chochk').toggle(this.ckhecked);
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testtablet">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="400px">

        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="testbody"></tbody>


</table>

<button type="button" id="chochk" style="display:none" class="sukuti">event</button>
```

Comment: this code looks so good yet Its not functioning for me , when I click my checkbox no event is done. I must be missing something once I figure out I will accept your answer

Comment: @david Change, and use the event delegation:  $('#testbody').on('change', ':checkbox.your', function (e) {   Let me know,

Comment: did not worked instead broke the table, does it matter if I am using the code inside the function instead of .ready(function?

Comment: when I check console it says object does not support method change

Comment: @david No, you must add the in dom ready the change event. Can you compare your code and the snippet in order to understand where the problem happens? thanks

Comment: finally figured out, I was getting checkbox as ID and you had it as class name. I changed ID to classname and it worked perfect.thx a lottttt

Answer (score 0):

1) do not use same ID for more than one element
use class instead

Comment: This should be a comment !